# Best access modifier for MODULE variable in any class file in java?

Tags: java, private, public, protected

Ok, let me start it with the following example to get a brief example

```
public class ClassA{
______ static final String MODULE = "[ClassA]";
}
```

in the blank space, I came across many code snippet it has some times `public` or `protected` or `private` but could not understand the which one is the best and why?.I know `protected` is best for `subclass` implementation  but then `subclass` to has `MODULE` variable.

basically `MODULE` is used in logging activities like for example

```
System.out.println(MODULE+"given message");
```

in-short which is best way to use for accessing?

Comment: @bigdestroyer It is perfectly valid to have a `protected static` class variable. The `protected` keyword is an _access modifier_. The purpose is to grant access to this variable to subclasses in other packages.

Comment: @bigdestroyer agreed with above comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically `MODULE` is used in logging activities...

Then I would suggest to make it `private`, because it will not be used outside the class (assuming that other classes have similar `static` constants).

Answer (score 5):

Like *anything*, you should give it the strictest access level that makes sense.

If it will only be used inside the class, use `private`. If it will only be used inside the package, use package access. If it could be used in subclasses, use `protected`. If it could be used by anyone, use `public`.

This applies to every class member in every programming language - it is by no means specific to fields named `MODULE` in Java.